# Can Wordpress Multisite use a nested subdirectory hierarchy?

Tags: wordpress, subdirectory, site-structure, permalinks

I have a WordPress subdirectory multisite installed. I have to achieve a 3-tier structure and multisite is based on a 2-tier structure but I though I could try the following:

- Main domain: `example.com` (1st tier)
- Subsite1: `example.com/province1` (2nd tier)
- Subsite2: `example.com/location1` (2nd tier)

Is it possible to have Subsite2 permalinked after the one like this:
`example.com/province1/location1`

Comment: I'll be open to other ideas too. Main idea is that I need hierarchically organized sites for the 3 different levels

Comment: Why use multisite at all?  It is possible to create such a URL structure in a single site WordPress install.

Comment: I need multiple independent websites with shared themes, cpts and functionalities, but independent user administration. We have over 100 potential websites under the 3rd level. To see them all in the same WP installation could be the mother-chaos.